# If child is not born even after several years of trying in marriage....is there anyway to escape from punnama hell?

Tags: garuda-purana

Option like changing my dharma from Hindu to Islam/christian where we can attain heaven even without child and  through only bhakthi....

Comment: Child doesn't take you to heaven. He will only save you from punnama hell. Your bhakti will save  There are methods in Hinduism where you can attain heaven. Changing dharma is a bad idea. Who said you can't attain heaven through bhakti? And who said a child is mandatory to go heaven?

Comment: Devi Bhagavatam 2.6.36-48

Once while he was listening to the religious discourses of the Munis, he heard unmistakeably the Munis telling that the man who is sonless can never go to the Heavens; so he must get a son somehow or other

Devi Bhagavatam 1.4.15-27

There is no prospect in the after birth of the sonless; never, never will Heaven be his. Without son, there is none other who can be of help in the next world. Thus in the Dharma S’âstras, Manu and other Munis declare that the man who has sons goes to Heaven and the sonless one can never go to Heaven. The man possessing a son is entitled

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61080/discussion-on-question-by-vishnu-guru-if-child-is-not-born-even-after-several-ye).

Comment: Marry second time or adopt a child whose whereabouts are known.

Comment: @Yogi marry second time and will end up in jail

Comment: @VishnuGuru Well you can consult with your wife :). If that is not possible just adopt a suitable child.

Comment: @Yogi 
It is not the progeny or various other rituals that give spiritual knowledge, Self-realization and ultimately Liberation (cessation of transmigration). Only the spiritual path alone will lead to the path of realization and Liberation. It is also said that if one begets a child, parent’s responsibilities increase manifold. Many times, sons and daughters are after wealth of their parents and do not shower love and affection. (One of greatest sins is repudiating aged parents and performing ceremonies after their deaths. One of the recent incidents goes like this: Aged mother passed away in

Comment: Came to know abt  prabodha Sudhakara  of Acharya bhagvatpadal...it says progeny is not needed to attain Mukthi

Comment: @VishnuGuru If you want moksha you have to clear all the sins...and for that you need to perform austere tapas and realize bramhan or just perform sharanagati. Btw the main goal of Grihastashrama is to produce a  righteous progeny and if that is not fulfilled then there is no meaning of Grihastashrama please don't take it otherwise you can just adopt an infant.

Comment: @Yogi but some of the Acharya's like Ramanuja, Govinda exit from grihasta ashrams without progeny...in modern day even Ramakrishna parahamsa

Comment: @Yogi it is very difficult to get a child for adoption nowadays...waiting list are for 8 years...earlier people used to produce 10 children's effortlessly...now it become difficult even to produce 1...

Comment: @VishnuGuru Bhagwad Ramanujacharya had performed Sharanagati so his karma balance was neutralized, and since he was Adishesha avatara he didn't have had any karma in the first place. I don't know who is Govinda and I don't believe in Ramkrishna Paramhansa so I won't comment on his doings. I am not an expert on Adoption, but you can go for surrogacy I don't know if its prescribed by Dharma shastras but its similar to Niyoga.

Comment: @Yogi Govinda Acharya is cousin of ramanaju Acharya....he gave his name embar to Govinda acharya

Comment: @VishnuGuru Oh you are talking about Sri Embaracharya he was freed from the sin because he performed Sharnagati at the lotus feet of Shriman Naryana.

Comment: @Yogi niyoga is prohibited in kaliyoga...dharma depends on Kalam too

Comment: @Yogi suroggacy is not legal in India...it is prohibited

Comment: @Yogi even bhagavan himself followed dharma as Krishna and Rama..then what is question of exempt for adhisesha...

Comment: @VishnuGuru I know that Niyoga is prohibited in Kaliyuga...and the reason is obvious. I said Surrogacy is similar not same as Niyoga, in surrogacy only womb is on rent and the foetus is from original parents. I don't know about legal status of surrogacy in India but here is the article http://indianexpress.com/article/research/karan-johar-surrogate-children-yash-roohi-what-are-the-surrogacy-in-laws-in-india-here-is-everything-you-need-to-know-4555077/

Comment: @VishnuGuru As to why Adisheshan is exempted it is because he was doing Bhagwad Seva, and because bhagwan says anayaschintayanto maam ye janaha paryupasate tesham nityabhi yuktanaam yogakshemam vahamyaham...and clearing sins is another pledge in  Bhagwans pledge in BG 18.66 surrender on to me and I will remove all your sins.