# Is stay in any of the narakas eternal?

Tags: puranas, karma, sin, naraka

[If child is not born even after several years of trying in marriage....is there anyway to escape from punnama hell?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19154/if-child-is-not-born-even-after-several-years-of-trying-in-marriage-is-there?noredirect=1#comment53365_19154) says stay in naraka for childless is eternal or at least till pralaya. Which scriptures mention duration of stay? Is stay in any other naraka eternal/till pralaya?

Comment: No it's not. Abrahmic religions & some philosophies talks about eternal staying in hell. Eternal staying in hell implies malevolence of God. Discard such religion or philosophy which talks about eternal staying at the hell.